# how to send variable data from javascript to node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, variables, nodes

I want to send the variable from javascript to node js

here I am storing some data in my javascript variable

```
var roomurl = "this is the data";
```

And here is my nodejs code

```
app.post("/newcall", function(req, res) {
  var n = (req.body.roomurl);
  console.log("val"+ n);
});
```

I have included all the dependencies like express and body parser

but I am not how to send it

can I get help in my javascript code or

any Url from where I can get to now about how do

I send data from java script to node js ?
thanks

Comment: To send data from your javascript, which I am guessing is client side to your node.js server, you need to make either a GET request or a POST request. There are many ways to send network requests, [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) is just one example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should run the node/express application to a specific port, ex 3000

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('App running at 3000')
})
```

Then from your client you should post your data via Fetch API or another http client like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/newcall', {
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({roomurl})
});
```

Comment: `client.js:2151 Uncaught ReferenceError: roomurl is not defined` I am getting this error @T.sardelis

Comment: Could you share your entire code? (Both client and server)